# Javascript function scope and calling from onclick

Tags: javascript, scope

With JavasScript, say there is an `innerFunction()` defined within an `outerFunction()`. If you attempt to call the `innerFunction()`, outside of the `outerFunction()`, there will be an error as it is not defined within the scope.
However, if while in the `outerFunction()`, you assign the `innerFunction()` to an event, say a click event, for some outside element, like a `button`, then the `innerFunction()` can be called from that scope of the button, whatever it may be. So why are you able to make this second call to `innerFunction()` froma  different scope.

I have a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rcmoore38/gPrMk/

The initial `changeColor()` call does not work, but when `changeColor()` is assigned to the `button`, it can be called via the button.

Thank you!

Comment: The functions are referenced in the event handlers, and they are all within scope ?

Comment: Why can `changeColor()` be called through the button,  but not initially, I understand when `changeColor()` is assigned to the button, it is within scope, but the button is not itself within scope.

Comment: In your code the line `$("#pid").css("color", function() { return get_random_color()});` can be changed to `$("#pid").css("color", get_random_color());` without loss of functionality.

Comment: Thanks @FritsvanCampen, I'm never sure when I need to include the function wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "scope of the button". What happens is that you're assigning the event listener from a scope where the inner function is visible, and that's all that matters in JavaScript. Scope in JS is about where functions are declared.

In your example:

```
$("#b").click(function() { changeColor() });
```

the function `changeColor` is available via [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) inside the anonymous function, because it's declared in an outer scope. When you define a nested function, all variables and functions from the parent functions will be available inside it. So when the element is clicked and the anonymous function is called, it still has a reference to `changeColor`, and is able to call it.

You could also set the event handler without using a closure, like this:

```
$("#b").click(changeColor);
```

As I said, the important thing is that `changeColor` is in scope when you *reference* it (not when it's actually called, in this case, by the browser).

Comment: Just to clarify, `changeColor()` would initially be able to access all variables in `gen()`, but after the initial call, it would only have its local variables, which would carry over like static variables in C?

Comment: No, all variables from all outer scopes are available within `changeColor`, whenever it's called - as long as you call it from somewhere where `changeColor` itself is visible.

Comment: And if those variables were to be changed in the outer function, `gen()`, they would be changed in the inner function, too, because they are all just references?

Comment: Yes, they will change (the classic example is a [closure inside a `for` loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)), unless you create new scopes to hold the different states of the variable.